# ext js grid example

Tags: extjs, grid, referenceerror

Firstly, sorry for my not very good english.

Problem:
I need to run ExtJS Grid with php. At the moment I want to run ext js grid at least (without generating json with php script).

Btw, I used this article in this example: 
http://extjstutorial.info/extjs-tutorial-paging-grid-with-php-and-mysql/24

I downloaded ext js library, unpacked it to root dir of my site: /public/extjs/. After that I included in  section required files for this script:

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/array-grid.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

Created file 'array-grid.js' in /js/ with this content:

```
Ext.onReady (function () {
var sampleData = [
    [1,'Monkey D Luffy','Captain','I will become the pirate king'],
    [2,'Roronoa Zoro','Swordman','Become the greatest swordman'],
    [3,'Sanji','Cook','Find all blue'],
    [4,'Usopp','Sniper','Become the greatest warrior'],
    [5,'Nami','Navigator','Draw map of the world']
];

// create the data store
var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name'},
        {name: 'position'},
        {name: 'ambition'}
    ]
});

// load data

store.loadData(sampleData);

// create the grid
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {id:'id',header: 'ID', width: 30, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'id'},
        {header: 'Name', width: 100, dataIndex: 'name'},
        {header: 'Position', width: 100, dataIndex: 'position'},
        {header: 'Ambition', width: 250, dataIndex: 'ambition'}
    ],
    stripeRows: true,
    height:180,
    width:500,
    title:'Straw Hats Crew'
});

// render grid to the grid-example element (see p array-grid.html)
grid.render('grid-example');        
});
```

Added in view this:

```
<div id="grid-example"></div>
```

After that , when I tried to load page nothing happened, grid wasn't displayed. 
Firebug says this:
http://habrastorage.org/storage3/ea4/a4e/2db/ea4a4e2dbb96c76c700be49293d49c10.png
(can't upload images because <10 rep)

It says: Reference error: Ext is not defined.

Whats the problem? Please, help me to solve it :)

All paths are right! I can check files content exactly in firebug (so paths are good, otherwise I wouldn't have seen anything)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now the answer!
I should include 2 extJS libs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```

I am using ZF2 and libs must be included like this:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/extjs/ext-all.js')
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js')
?>
```

and in code it will look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Check the order. Base was included 2nd in zf2, but in source its 1st. They swapped in source. There was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is one quick thing. you have passed a different ID to the render method.

```
    `grid.render('grid-example');`
```

and in your html, you have set your id to "paging-grid".

try matching the two IDs so you won't get a dom reference error.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - ext-all includes ext-base. wouldnt that be redundant?

Comment: It doesn't include ext-base.

Comment: oh! my bad, sry, failed a bit. html-code is ok. id is 'grid-example', i copypasted from another page, sry. id in html and id in argument is equal.

Answer (score 1):

Sharikov,

Everything is just fine, I just copied your code and **tried it myself, it works fine.**

Checkout(double and triple) the name of the folders, files and the paths (it is a fact that the code works).

**Code does work.**

Comment: Ty for your answer. Btw firstname is Vladislav :D Very strange. What browser do you have? what version you used? I used 3.4 downloaded from sencha.com , this link : http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/

Comment: Checked links again. All links fine.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, with ExtJs 4.2.1 (ext-base.js does give me 404 at that relative location) anyway I see rendered the grid. Is there any special reason to use 3.4 ? I love MVC of Ext4.

Comment: Nope. I just clicked download and they gave me link for 3.4.0. Ah, remember I tried 4.2.1 but there are new structure of files and folders, so I rolled back to 3.4.0. Thats why 3.4. Btw chrome doesn't show any errors, but FireFox does.

Comment: 1.- Believe me go to Ext4 version you will love it. 2.- so it does render in chrome or it is only not showing any errors?

Comment: It just not showing any errors I think. Strange. Anyway problem is solved. Look my answer. Next time I would pay more attention to details, exactly with things that I don't know so good :) Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Your ExtJS library may be at the wrong place because there is Error "Ext is not defined".

Comment: Thank you for answer. Ye, I think about it. But look there: http://habrastorage.org/storage3/5df/b8d/537/5dfb8d537d9f853771f38b5111aabb20.png , I can look content of file throw firebug, so it works. Also, if I press RMB on page, 'show source code' and click on link ext-base or ext-all, browser will show codes, not 404. So its okay with paths. Right?